# How to properly write this query

Tags: mongodb, python-2.7, pymongo

Using pymongo v2.6, what it a proper way to write a find query with these conditions:

```
select * from tasks where processed = 0 AND (process_lock_date is null or process_lock_date < now - 10 minutes) order by date_added asc limit 50
```

Basically need to write the query to select 50 records that haven't been picked up by a processor yet or haven't been processed and were picked up more than 10 minutes ago (ie pickup unprocessed tasks that were picked up longer time ago and didn't get marked as processed in case previous processor failed)

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to import the timedelta and datetime objects first to create a date object that represents the datetime 10 minutes ago, use that object for you mongodb query as follows:

```
from datetime import timedelta 

date = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(minutes=10)
docs = db.collection.find(
    {
        'processed': 0,
        '$or': [
            {'process_lock_date': {'$lt': date}},
            {'process_lock_date': null}
        ]
    }).sort({'date_added': 1}).limit(50)

for doc in docs:
    print(doc)
```

Comment: And I guess I would wrap all of that with 

"$and": ["parsed":0, "$or".....]

and is there a way to update process_lock_date within this select directly, or do I need to loop through selected docs first to collect all _ids and then run a separate update to update process_lock_date on what was selected?

Comment: @AlexSmirnov You could do that yes but it's not necessary to explicitly include the **`$and`** operator in your query. See my updated response.

Comment: @AlexSmirnov Could you elaborate further your other query where you want to update the `process_lock_date` with the same query by perhaps creating a new question?